# MySQL FullText search on string shorter than 3 chars returns no rows

Tags: mysql, innodb, index, full-text-search

I have a MySQL table with some addresses in it. Let's say I have the following 2 rows:

```
"10 Fake Street"
"101 Fake Street"
```

I'm trying to use fulltext search with MATCH() AGAINST(). I have set ft_min_word_len to 1, rebooted the server and dropped and then rebuilt the index by running

```
ALTER TABLE addresses DROP INDEX address_index
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX address_index ON addresses(street)
```

I have verified that my ft_min_word_len is indeed set to 1 by running

```
show global variables like 'ft_min_word_len'
```

If I include any word in my search that's shorter than 3 characters, I get no results back, unless I append a wildstar to it. For example

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE MATCH(street) AGAINST('+101' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE MATCH(street) AGAINST('+10*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

both return 1 row "101 Fake Street". Running

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE MATCH(street) AGAINST('+10' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

returns 0 rows. Why? The only suggestions I can find online all talk about setting min length, but I already verified that mine is set to 1 and rebuilt the index.

Comment: @Mihai I'm InnoDB on MySQL 5.6.19

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting [**ft_min_word_len**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) only affects MyISAM.

You need to set [**innodb_ft_min_token_size to 1**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size) since the default is 3.

Once you set [**innodb_ft_min_token_size to 1**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size), go back and do

```
ALTER TABLE addresses DROP INDEX address_index
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX address_index ON addresses(street);
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks! I guess since InnoDB only recently started supporting full text searches, most of the resources and answers online only mentioned the MyISAM variable.

Comment: You can also rebuild index by running:
```
USE db;
OPTIMIZE TABLE tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried @RolandMySQLDBA solution, but still no results.
The query is simple:

`SELECT * FROM agreement a WHERE MATCH (a.title) AGAINST ('it*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

The table is MyISAM, the `title` column has row with exact value: `Systems IT`, `innodb_ft_min_token_size` value is `1`. The index was recreated. And no rows found... Any idea?