# Any known issues upgrading from MySQL 5.1.73 to 5.6.21?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, upgrade, mysql-5.1, mysql-5

I am planning my MySQL DB ver5.1.73 running on a CentOS 6.5 machine to MySQL 5.6.21.

I understand the basic procedure for this based on what I have read on StackOverflow, but I was curious if anyone has encountered any specific problems when they have gone the 5.1 to 5.6 route?

One that I have heard of is that certain TIMESTAMP columns might end up with incorrect timestamps. But I am curious if there are any other ones that people have heard of or run into.

To narrow down on the issues I am concerned about, I am only concerned of anything where there might be data loss or consistency issues

Thanks! IS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## ISSUE #1 : Upgrade Path

Your grant tables can get screwed up because you are leaping two versions instead of one.

I just helped someone a week ago because they did just that ([MySQL service stops after trying to grant privileges to a user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78923/mysql-service-stops-after-trying-to-grant-privileges-to-a-user/78927#78927)). The solution for that question was to manually fix the `mysql.user`. Rather than going through that heavy-handed route, there are two ways go about this.

#### TECHNIQUE #1 : Upgrade the Politically Correct Way

- Upgrade From MySQL 5.1 to MySQL 5.5
- Run `mysql_upgrade --upgrade-system-tables` using MySQL 5.5's binaries
- Upgrade From MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 5.6
- Run `mysql_upgrade --upgrade-system-tables` using MySQL 5.6's binaries
- Generate the System Tables that use InnoDB (See my post [InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found after upgrade to mysql 5.6](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54608/innodb-error-table-mysql-innodb-table-stats-not-found-after-upgrade-to-mys/54624#54624)) since the [MySQL 5.6 version of mysql_upgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-upgrade.html) does not create them.

#### TECHNIQUE #2 : Upgrade Directly from MySQL 5.1 to MySQL 5.6

I already described how to upgrade two versions

- `Apr 11, 2013` : [MySQL upgrade 5.0.88 to latest](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39716/mysql-upgrade-5-0-88-to-latest/39763#39763) (Best Reference)
- `Feb 08, 2012` : [will replication from 5.5.20 to 5.0.XX server work?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12509/will-replication-from-5-5-20-to-5-0-xx-server-work/12511#12511)
- `Jul 26, 2011` : [Restoring an old backup to latest MySQL release](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4114/restoring-an-old-backup-to-latest-mysql-release/4127#4127)

## ISSUE #2 : FULLTEXT Indexes

If you use FULLTEXT indexes before MySQL 5.6, those tables use the MyISAM Storage Engine. You need to convert those tables to InnoDB (See my post [When to switch from MyISAM to InnoDB?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22678/when-to-switch-from-myisam-to-innodb/22680#22680) under `NEED #2`). Then, separately tune the InnoDB FULLTEXT options (See my post [MySQL FullText search on string shorter than 3 chars returns no rows](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76036/mysql-fulltext-search-on-string-shorter-than-3-chars-returns-no-rows/76037#76037)).

## ISSUE #3 : Security Issues

I am sure you are aware of this since you are going straight to MySQL 5.6.21

For the rest who do not know, as of October 16, 2014, [Oracle just announced that there are security issues with MySQL 5.5 and MySQL 5.6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/cpuoct2014-1972960.html#AppendixMSQL). This was also [announced at Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/security/security-bulletins/mysql-5-5-and-5-6-security-advisory/). Both MySQL 5.5.40 and MySQL 5.6.21 will have the security patches in places, so it is best to upgrade to one of these.