# Find MySQL Patch Level

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

What command do you use to find the patch level of MySQL?  I am currently on 5.1.73.  I need to find out what patches have been applied to this database.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

There is no command to execute for this. What you need are the following:

- [Oracle MySQL Executive Summary (under `Supported Versions Affected`)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/cpujan2014-1972949.html#AppendixMSQL)
- [MySQL 5.1 Release Notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.1/en/)

I would be concerned because [MySQL 5.1 was last updated Dec 03, 2013](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,601500,601500#msg-601500) and the Last Critical Patch to MySQL 5.1 was Jan 2014 (See [Patch Availability Table under column `Patch Availability and Installation Information`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/cpujan2014-1972949.html#AppendixMSQL))

On Oct 17, 2014, I posted the answer to [Any known issues upgrading from MySQL 5.1.73 to 5.6.21?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80499/any-known-issues-upgrading-from-mysql-5-1-73-to-5-6-21/80503#80503) following the security patch announcement. MySQL 5.1.73 has had no security patch applied. Only MySQL 5.6 (5.6.21) and 5.5 (5.5.40) have new patches.

What's crazy is that [MySQL 5.6.20 was released two months](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,618340,618340#msg-618340) prior to [MySQL 5.6.21](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,620928,620928#msg-620928). Again, no mention of MySQL 5.1.73.

***I highly recommend you upgrade to MySQL 5.6.21.***