# Joining two Mysql VIEWs takes a very long time

Tags: mysql, performance, join, view, query-performance

I have a textbox (for which I used jQuery auto-completion) in my PHP form where user can insert an actor/actress name and then by clicking "Search" button, a new window is opened showing list of movies by that actor/actress.

This is a query where I get movies by actor name:

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT c.movieName, c.castName, c.movieImdbId, f.year, f.posterLink FROM cast_movie as c JOIN film_info as f ON c.ImdbId = f.ImdbId WHERE c.castName LIKE :q");
 $query->execute(array(':q' => '%' . $searchText . '%' ));
```

**My question:**

The above query works fine if user select a name from auto-completion list. However I would like to enable user to write any name (even if he couldn't find from auto-completion list). For example, If user write "tom" in the textbox, and click on "search" button, I want to show list of all movies by all actors that their name containing word "tom".

For this purpose, I used `LIKE :q` and `':q' => '%' . $searchText . '%'` in the above query, but the query never ends!!(I think because cast_movie is a VIEW which is quite large (with 3 million rows) and joining this view with the other table takes a very long time (actually I waited for 10 minutes and it didn't finished yet).

Could someone kindly let me know if there is any way to fix this? (I read we can use index for joining very large tables, but I think it's not possible to define index for cast_movie since it is VIEW.)

**More info about tables and views:**

**cast_movie** is a view which is made by joining "movie_roleNames" and "movies".

**movie_roleNames** is also a view which is made by joining two tables "Cast" and "nameRoles".

**film_info** is also a view that is made by joining two tables "movies" and "movies_info".

The structure of the above tables:

table **"movies"**: *Id, movieName, ImdbId*(unique Id of movies), Rate, numVotes, year (**indexes**: *ImdbId, movieName, year*)

table **"cast"**: *castName, castImdbID* (unique Id of casts) (**indexes**: *castName, castImdbID*)

table **"nameRoles"**: *Id, castImdbId, movieImdbId, role_Id,* (**indexes**: *movieImdbId, castImdbId)*

VIEW **"movie_roleNames"**: *Id, castName, castImdbId, movieImdbId* and the join statement was: `SELECT n.Id, c.castName, n.castImdbId, n.movieImdbId FROM nameRoles as n join Cast as c ON n.castImdbId = c.castImdbID`

VIEW **"cast_movie"**: *Id, castName, castImdbId, movieImdbId, movieName* and the join statement was: `SELECT m.Id, r.castName, r.castImdbId, r.movieImdbId, m.movieName FROM movie_roleNames AS r JOIN movies AS m ON r.movieImdbId = m.ImdbId`

All ideas are highly appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

Using FULLTEXT indexes has to be handled with great care. Why ? While FULLTEXT index searches do work, the MySQL Query optimizer tends to suggest full table scans if you do not express the query properly.

Let's take your query and look for 'tom'

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.movieName, c.castName, c.movieImdbId, f.year, f.posterLink
FROM cast_movie as c JOIN film_info as f ON c.ImdbId = f.ImdbId
WHERE c.castName LIKE '%tom%';
```

This joins everything. Then, it scans the resulting temp table and returns every row with `tom`.

Let's implement the FULLTEXT method

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.movieName, c.castName, c.movieImdbId, f.year, f.posterLink
FROM cast_movie as c JOIN film_info as f ON c.ImdbId = f.ImdbId
WHERE MATCH(c.castName) AGAINST ('+tom' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I can almost assure you that a full table scan will occur during the join because I have experienced it hundreds of times:

- `Oct 25, 2011` : [FULLTEXT index ignored in BOOLEAN MODE with 'number of words' conditional](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7136/fulltext-index-ignored-in-boolean-mode-with-number-of-words-conditional/7216#7216)
- `Jan 26, 2012` : [Mysql fulltext search my.cnf optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11716/mysql-fulltext-search-my-cnf-optimization/11730#11730)
- `May 07, 2012` : [MySQL EXPLAIN doesn't show 'use index' for FULLTEXT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17502/mysql-explain-doesnt-show-use-index-for-fulltext/17545#17545)
- `Jul 18, 2012` : [Why full-text-search returns less rows than LIKE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21118/why-full-text-search-returns-less-rows-than-like/21128#21128)

I started writing posts about FULLTEXT and query refactoring ever since I saw a post from  [webmasterworld.com entitled *MySQL Match Against + a very expensive join. How do I optimize this?*](http://www.webmasterworld.com/databases_sql_mysql/4229410.htm)

Given the information I just mentioned let's take your query and refactor it to handle the FULLTEXT and stilldo a good join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.movieName, c.castName, c.movieImdbId, f.year, f.posterLink
FROM cast_movie as c JOIN film_info as f ON c.ImdbId = f.ImdbId
WHERE MATCH(c.castName) AGAINST ('+tom' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

First, apply the [`MATCH ... AGAINST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) operator to `cast_movie` and return `ImdbId` and other fields

```
SELECT ImdbId,movieName,castName,movieImdbId FROM cast_movie
WHERE MATCH(c.castName) AGAINST ('+tom' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Make that a subquery to provide keys to join and retrieve data from `film_info`

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.movieName, c.castName, c.movieImdbId, f.year, f.posterLink FROM
(
    SELECT ImdbId,movieName,castName,movieImdbId FROM cast_movie
    WHERE MATCH(c.castName) AGAINST ('+tom' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) as c JOIN film_info as f ON c.ImdbId = f.ImdbId;
```

This should produce a better result.

If your tables use InnoDB Storage Engine, remember to tune the InnoDB Fulltext options. Any fulltext option that does not start with `innodb_` is meant for MyISAM (See my post [MySQL FullText search on string shorter than 3 chars returns no rows](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76036/mysql-fulltext-search-on-string-shorter-than-3-chars-returns-no-rows/76037#76037))

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for great info and explanation. Actually, I fixed my problem by joining tables (instead of views), so I could define indexes on tables and joined those tables.. the query now is ok, and also in terms of time it works well.. however, I really appreciate the useful information you wrote for me and I'm sure I will need to use them soon :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on the subject, but I'd recommend you look into FULLTEXT searches and indexes. From what I understand, they're much more efficient than LIKE statements for searching for part of a string. [Here's the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) on the feature.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. I don't know about FULLTEXT (I will read your link now), but about indexes, as far as I know (if I am not mistaken), it is not possible to define indexes on VIEWS.. however, tnx, I will read your link now...

Comment: You're right, that's not really an option. You can use it without the indexes, but it's slower (probably still faster than the current implementation, though). Any chance you could try without referencing the view, maybe by hard-coding the queries into your script or by using a stored procedure? That way you could build the indexes on the tables and utilize them.